# Silverlight WCF service not working when deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I have a WCF service method in a Silverlight application that inserts some data into a SQL Server database deployed on a shared GoDaddy server.  Some of the methods work, and some do not, but all of them work when the application is run locally (with a local database).  I get the generic "The remote server returned an error: NotFound", and I can't seem to get any more info.  When I run the method directly from the service class (not through the service reference), it works correctly.  Here is the service part of my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
   <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="default">
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
         <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
       </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>

   <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
       <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IncreasedBuffer" 
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
         <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" 
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
       </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <services>
     <service name="GreekTools.Services.DataService"
        behaviorConfiguration="default">
       <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                 bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IncreasedBuffer"
                 contract="GreekTools.Contracts.IDataService" />
       <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                 contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     </service>
   </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you forgot to include the rest of your serviceModel config...

Comment: in order for your XML config stuff to show up, you need to select it and then click on the "code" button (010 101) in the toolbar! Otherwise, people won't be able to see it......

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong with the binding configuration...

Comment: Is any of the given answers the correct one? If so, could you mark it as such?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually the case when you attempt to do a request on a url that does not exist. For example, you expect a service to be at `http://hostname/path/Service.svc` but it actually lives at `http://hostname/Service.svc`.

Your best course of action is to download a web debugging tool ([Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a good choice) and check the actual requests that are sent from your Silverlight client to your web server. Very probably you'll see some problem with a url path that's incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have an older version of the dll deployed on the server side. That would explain why some work and some do not.

If this is not the case, is there any pattern in what works and what does not?